# How to get PostgreSQL Backup Database by command in centos7 Operating System?

Tags: postgresql, centos, database-backups

I am using PostgreSQL database in CentOS 7.

I can restore backup database by

```
psql -h localhost -U adempiere sd -f /home/DatabaseName
```

Now how to perform a PostgreSQL backup by command in CentOS 7?

Comment: What is wrong with calling `pg_dump`?

Comment: here sd mean database name

Comment: Try this: [How To Back Up, Restore, and Migrate PostgreSQL Databases with Barman on CentOS 7](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-back-up-restore-and-migrate-postgresql-databases-with-barman-on-centos-7)

Comment: Maybe you used the wrong `pg_dump` - take the one in the same directory as the `psql` that works.

Comment: [root@zakir ~]# pg_dump -U adempiere sd | gzip > /home/sd_15102018 pg_dump: error while loading shared libraries: libsasl2.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory [root@zakir ~]#

Comment: Have you installed all the postgresql components? What was your install command exactly?

Comment: 1st>>>>>>>> [root@zakir opt]# chmod 777 postgresql-9.1.1-1-linux-x64.bin                     2nd>>>>>>>  [root@zakir opt]# ./postgresql-9.1.1-1-linux-x64.bin